# Matter.js body without rotation around its center

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am working with Matter.js and I am struggling with many aspects because it's very hard to find anything in the documentation.

The most important thing I would like to know is how to make this body:

```
Game.characters[1] = Game.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, c_width, c_height, {
    id: "character1",
    isStatic: false,
    friction: 0.002
});
```

not rotate around its center. I want this body to be character sprite with frame animations and I just want it to be able to jump and move left or right, but not tilt if it hits an edge or if it does anything that would make it tilt.

Answer (score 6):

So I had the same question but just found the answer.

[According to the developer](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/39) of Matter.js setting inertia of a body to Infinite prevents the body from rotation on collision.

When creating a [Matter.Body](http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html), set the `inertia` property of the body to `Infinity`:

```js
const options = {
    inertia: Infinity,
}
let body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, options);
```

Comment: This approach didn't work for me on version 0.19.0. Instead, I successfully used Matter.Body.setInertia(myBody, Infinity)

Answer (score 0):

Inertia did not work for me..
for now I'm doing this on update.

```
this.characters[1].setAngle(0)
```

Comment: This hack will likely cause weird behaviour over time, due to small rotations occurring before being reset. Matter.Body.setInertia(myBody, Infinity) appears to work instead.